# Python - opening a file and converting row to columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

please excuse me, i just started learning Python as a first programming language. i am looking to open a file that has a row of numbers, separated by spaces, i would like to open the file, convert the rows into one column. i was able to do this by couple of ways, the problem isn't so much about doing it as much as it is as "How am i getting this results?"

here is what i did :

#### First approach:

```
Myfile = Open ('C:/Python/training_Examples/row.txt')
myfile = Myfile.read()
Myfiles = str(myfile)
for i in Myfiles:
    print (i)
```

#### Second Approach:

```
Myfile = Open ('C:/Python/training_Examples/row.txt')
myfile = Myfile.read()
Myfiles = str(myfile)
File = Myfiles.replace(" ", "\n")
for i in File:
    print (i)
```

The second one added an additional row but it did translate the space separated numbers into columns, the question is from my first approach, why did it convert the row into one column?

Comment: I gave an answer below, but I'm wondering why exactly you want to convert the data in the file to a "row". When you print the file's contents it shows up on multiple rows in the output terminal, but that's really because the data _is_ a row. It's just a byproduct of how things are printed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand why this happened, just consider the following simple example

```
myString = '12345'
for character in myString:
    print character
```

The output will look like this:

```
>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
>>> 5
```

The reason this happens is that the `for` loop is iterating over each character in the string and the `print` statement prints each of those characters on its own line.

If the first line of your original file had looked like this

`This is the first line in the file`

then your output would have been

```
>>> T
>>> h
>>> i
>>> s
>>> 
>>> i
>>> s
>>> 
>>> t
>>> h
>>> e
...
```

To summarize, strings can be iterated over, just like lists, so the `for` loop gave you one character at a time and the `print` statement put each character on its own line.

Comment: Great answer! I wanted to explicitly point out that the `print` function by default add's it's own newline character to whatever string you passed it. So executing `print "\n"` will print a newline character, followed by an additional newline.

Comment: So in the example you provided above, how can i separate those words into their own row?

this way, each word would be by its own.

Comment: If you want to print each word on a separate line (don't use the word "row" as it means something else that you don't intend) you can replace each space with a newline character. For example, you could do myString = myString.replace(' ', '\n') and then print(myString). You should ask this in a separate question though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand well. You say you have to convert the row in the file into a column.

Both of your solutions only **display** the data in a column, but they **don't write it to a file**. To really convert one file into the other you have to create a separate file and write into it.

Also your approches don't work if there is more than one line.

One method would be to read the file into a list of rows and each row into a list of numbers. Then you iterate with for over this two-dimensional list to write it to a new file.